# Time array ( 10 min ) for start time to next time in time series import from csv file using python

Tags: python

Here I have time series import from csv file. Start time 7.00 a.m next time is 8.00 a.m next time is 9.00a.m like that it will continue till to midnight. Then again next day it will start with time 7.00 a.m . So here I want to write a time array for starting time to next time with time delta 10 min. Can you help me to solve this problem? Here I wrote one code , but I don't know how to add start time from my dataset import from csv file.

my code is:

```
def datetime_range(start,end,delta):
    current = start
    while current < end:
        yield current
        current += delta
data = pd.read_csv('data6.csv')
dts = [data.strftime('%Y-%m-%d T%H:%M') for data in 
       datetime_range(datetime(2018, 9, 28, 7), datetime(2018, 9, 28, 7+2), 
       timedelta(minutes=10))]
print(dts)
```

Output:

```
['2018-09-28 T07:00', '2018-09-28 T07:10', '2018-09-28 T07:20', '2018-09-28 T07:30', '2018-09-28 T07:40', '2018-09-28 T07:50', '2018-09-28 T08:00', '2018-09-28 T08:10', '2018-09-28 T08:20', '2018-09-28 T08:30', '2018-09-28 T08:40', '2018-09-28 T08:50']
```

Here I upload how output is came according to my code. But I have to mentioned the start time and end time and it is not read from the csv file. Can anyone give me any suggestions to solve his problem?

Comment: Please post your actual code and actual output of your code, instead of **screenshots** of them

Comment: @user12075 I upload my actual code and actual output.

Comment: great. Your `datetime_range()` seems to be working as expected. Now what's the format of the *start time* when you read from the csv file? If it's a string, can you parse it with `strptime()`?

Comment: I wrote the  code for that, @user12075 I parse it with strptime() . Here is my code ; data['Time']= data['Time'].apply(lambda x:dt.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y/%m/%d:%H:%M:%S')) print(data['Time']).